# Free Files Hosting URL Checker

Tags: linkchecker

I'm looking for URL Checker to use in my project. It can be PHP or JS. Like [urlchecker.org](http://urlchecker.org).
turbobit.net, mega.nz, mediafire.com to query the status of the file uploaded on sites such as.

Comment: Hey Onur, per the Stack Overflow help center terms of use, this question is considered "off-topic" for Stack Overflow given "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: The way to make this on topic is to specifically ask the question, but not reference those offsite resources like this: "I have this PHP code, __insert simple exmaple__ and I want to be able to handle the condition where the user enters an incorrect URL. Is there a way that I can check a URL using PHP or JS"?